# set additional folder for snmp MIBs

Tags: snmp, nagios, mib

I am rebuilding an Icinga server that has been left behind by a previous employee. I have everything up and running, except for a bunch of MIB files for 3com switches that I cannot get to work.

The server is a CentOS 6 OpenVZ container.

In the original server there is a bunch of mib files in the default location at `/usr/share/snmp/mibs/` and the 3com ones at `/usr/share/snmp/mibs/3Com_4500/MIBs`. The 3Com mibs work fine:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H 10.10.111.11 -P 2c -C public -o hwDevMFanStatus.65536 -s "active(1)" -m A3COM-HUAWEI-LswDEVM-MIBSNMP OK - active(1) |
```

In the new server, the MIBs in the 3com folder do not get acknowledged and I get errors like the following:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H 10.10.111.11 -P2c -C someuser -o hwDevMFanStatus.65536 -s "active(1)" -m A3COM-HUAWEI-LswDEVM-MIB
External command error: No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
Cannot find module (A3COM-HUAWEI-LswDEVM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
hwDevMFanStatus.65536: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> hwDevMFanStatus)
```

`/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` is identical for both servers and so is `/etc/sysconfig/snmp`.

`set` does not show any ENV variable related to snmp or mib.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `snmpd.conf` and `snmp.conf` the former being the configuration file for the SNMP *daemon* whereas Net-SNMP `applications` use `snmp.conf`.

The `mibs`/`mibdirs` directives you are interested in would be specified in `snmp.conf` (see also `man snmp.conf`.